# Attempting to find a name in a range of names - getting error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I believe the issue is in the range I have named 'AllNames' because when I walk through I see that 'BaseName' Range calls up correctly the string value in D1. This was meant to be simple exercise, but I am completely stuck as to how to correct the issue. When I use the Watches Window I get Type 'Object/Range' for both so I'm not sure where the mismatch is occurring.

```
Sub FindName()

Dim AllNames As Range
Dim BaseName As Range

Set AllNames = Range("a1", "c6")
Set BaseName = Range("D1")

For Each BaseName In AllNames
    If StrComp(BaseName.Value, AllNames.Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
        AllNames.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next BaseName

End Sub
```

The end result is that the Range known as BaseName will have its cell background changed when it is found in the larger Range of AllNames. Instead I get Runtime Error 13

Answer (score 1):

The easy part first - incorrect code is causing your error:

```
   If StrComp(BaseName.Value, AllNames.Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
```

In your code, `BaseName` is now a single cell, but `AllNames` is an array of values and you are trying to do `StrComp` between a potential string and an array of potential strings.

Now for the off-topic hints:

- Use `Option Explicit` always.
- Your `AllNames` Range is not what you think it is (did you mean
  `.Range("A1:C6")`?)
- Your loop destroys your early assignment to `BaseName` because you
  use `BaseName` to iterate through the loop.
- You should fully qualify your ranges to avoid any `ActiveSheet`
  issues.

Revised code:

```
Sub FindName()
Dim allNames As Range
Dim baseName As String ' Avoid referring to the Excel range to improve performance.
Dim cellIterator as Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ` amend as required
        Set AllNames = .Range("A1:C6")
        Set BaseName = .Range("D1").Value

        For Each cellIterator In AllNames
            If StrComp(BaseName, cellIterator.Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                cellIterator.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next cellIterator 
    End With
End Sub
```

Not tested.

Comment: To the second bullet, yes, I tried that format in the immediate window and it capture the area I was going for, but I'm open to whatever way is the most efficient/correct. I have tried what you posted but I am getting object required at the line 'Set BaseName ..'

Comment: Thanks AJD for your input, It got me thinking in a different manner about what was missing/wrong. The issue was how to compare each cell individually(one at a time) instead of, as you pointed out, compare the multi cell range to a single cell range.  I stripped things back so I'm only dealing with one column of names. I'll work on developing it into more than one column but for now i'll take the victory and expand to multiple columns a later date.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

This function will find the name (D1) that is listed in A1 through C6:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub FindName()

        Dim AllNames As Range
        Dim BaseName As Range
        Dim rngItem As Range

        Set AllNames = Range("A1:C6")
        Set BaseName = Range("D1")

        For Each rngItem In AllNames
            'strComp returns -1, 0, and 1.
            '-1 if string1 is less than string2
            '0 if they are equal
            ' 1 if string1 is greater than string2
            If StrComp(rngItem.Value, BaseName.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                rngItem.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next

        Set AllNames = Nothing
        Set BaseName = Nothing
        Set rngItem = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ColourDuplicateName()

Dim baseName As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set baseName = Range("b1")

For I = 1 To 7
    If StrComp(baseName.Value, Cells(I, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
    Cells(I, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next I

End With
End Sub
```